# Problems converting VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, asmx, vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to convert some vb.net to C#, but I keep getting errors.  At the moment, I am getting the following error:

```
The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context
```

The problem line is:

```
strUser = Strings.LCase(Strings.Trim(strUserInitials[strUserInitials.GetUpperBound(0)])).ToString();
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

I have the following namespaces set:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I am working on a webservice (asmx file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.aspx) utility class is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

You can add a reference to the library and use it from your C# code, or rewrite the calls:

```
strUser = strUserInitials[strUserInitials.GetUpperBound(0)].ToString().Trim().ToLower();
```

Answer (score 3):

In c# there is no `Strings` class in `System` namespace. and in the `string` change `LCase` to `ToLower`, So:

```
strUser = string.ToLower(string.Trim(strUserInitials[strUserInitials.GetUpperBound(0)]));
```